# Batch script prepend and append text to files

Tags: batch-file, append, rename, prepend

I need to add a few lines of text to the beginning and end of several files.

I want so use a batch script to do this.

The first thing I'm doing is replacing the file extensions and changing them to XMP.

Originally, the filenames follow this structure `DJI_0035.mp4.json`.

So I start with:

`set mypath=%~dp0
ren *.mp4.json *.xmp`

Then, I need to prepend:

```
<?xpacket begin='﻿' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x='adobe:ns:meta/' x:xmptk='Image::ExifTool 11.65'>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>


 <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
  xmlns:exif='http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/'>
  <exif:UserComment>
   <rdf:Alt>
    <rdf:li xml:lang='x-default'>
```

And then append:

```
</rdf:li>
   </rdf:Alt>
  </exif:UserComment>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end='w'?>
```

To append I tried doing:

```
FOR %%G IN (*) DO echo "</rdf:li>
   </rdf:Alt>
  </exif:UserComment>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end='w'?>" >> %%G "%~dp0"
```

This works with simple strings but not with the XML code.

How  do I get around this problem?

Comment: Due to the syntax rules for XML, you should not consider batch-files for this task unless they in turn leverage another language or utility which understands the syntax and uses appropriate encoding. I would strongly advise that you focus your attention on PowerShell, searching and writing your code using it.

Comment: I'd put the header and footer data into separate files, then use [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) and its `+` option in a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to combine each target file with them...

Comment: Python has excellent XML and text editing tools.  Might this be an option to consider?

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that adds a header and trailer record which might do what you want:

```
:addHeaderAndTrailer
:: step 1 store headers and trailers into temp files
echo:%~1>_hdr.tmp
echo:%~2>_tlr.tmp

:: step 2 Concatenate the three
copy /a _hdr.tmp+%~3+_tlr.tmp _new.tmp>nul
move /y _new.tmp %~3>nul& rem 'move' saves a couple of copy/del steps

:: step 3 cleanup and exit
del _hdr.tmp & del _tlr.tmp

exit /b

:: /addHeaderAndTrailer

::addHeaderAndTrailer [1] [2] [3]
::===================
::FUNCTION appends header and trailer records into logs or other files
::PARAMETERS:
:: 1= Header Record
:: 1=  [/h] : this help screen
:: 2= Trailer Record
:: 3= Filename
::    if file doesn't exist, creates with just the headers and trailers
```

Comment: you would need to populate the header and trailer strings, of course.